# MySql self join predicate not understanding how it works

Tags: mysql, self-join

I am learning about self joins and have this simple table:

```
+-----------+-------------+
| name      | location    |
+-----------+-------------+
| Robert    | Guadalajara |
| Manuel    | Guadalajara |
| Dalia     | Guadalajara |
| Alejandra | Guadalajara |
| Luis      | Guadalajara |
| Monica    | Guadalajara |
| Claudia   | Guadalajara |
| Scartlet  | Guadalajara |
| Sergio    | Guadalajara |
| Rick      | Mexico City |
| Rene      | Mexico City |
| Ramon     | Culiacan    |
| Junior    | Culiacan    |
| Kasandra  | Culiacan    |
| Emma      | Culiacan    |
| Johnatha  | Dunedin     |
| Miriam    | Largo       |
| Julie     | Largo       |
+-----------+-------------+
```

What was intended was to find all the people who share the same location as 'Robert'.

Using self joins I saw that the following works from reading about solutions on here but, I don't understand what is going on and would not be able to explain it to another if they asked me how it worked:

```
SELECT users1.name
FROM users users1, users users2
WHERE users1.location = users2.location
AND users2.name = 'Robert';
```

Correctly returns the following result:

```
+-----------+
| name      |
+-----------+
| Robert    |
| Manuel    |
| Dalia     |
| Alejandra |
| Luis      |
| Monica    |
| Claudia   |
| Scartlet  |
| Sergio    |
+-----------+
```

What I don't understand specifically is how the `AND users2.name = 'Robert'` plays a role in returning the correct result.

Can someone explain step by step how MySql processes the table expression and predicate:

```
WHERE users1.location = users2.location
AND users2.name = 'Robert';
```

to return the correct result.

Comment: Please review the answer given below, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually prefer to use explicit syntax in a self-join which makes it easier to see that you are actually joining together two tables (or a table to itself in this case):

```
SELECT u2.name
FROM users u1 INNER JOIN users u2
ON u1.location = u2.location
WHERE u1.name = 'Robert'
```

A picture is worth a thousand words, so here is what the temporary table created in the above query looks like:

```
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| u1.name   | u1.location | u2.name   | u2.location |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
| Robert    | Guadalajara | Robert    | Guadalajara |
| Robert    | Guadalajara | Manuel    | Guadalajara |
| Robert    | Guadalajara | Dalia     | Guadalajara |
| Robert    | Guadalajara | Alejandra | Guadalajara |
| Robert    | Guadalajara | Luis      | Guadalajara |
| Robert    | Guadalajara | Monica    | Guadalajara |
| Robert    | Guadalajara | Claudia   | Guadalajara |
| Robert    | Guadalajara | Scarlet   | Guadalajara |
| Robert    | Guadalajara | Sergio    | Guadalajara |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+-------------+
```

The query joins each location on the first `users` table to each matching location in the second `users` table.  The `WHERE` clause restricts to only users named `'Robert'` in the first table.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Nevertheless, I still don't understand my query and why and how it works.